# Chartjs updating point titles

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, chart.js

I am trying to update update the title of a points on a chart I made, it is updating it fine, but when i add a point it will as so.

First point added will be called 'point 1', Second point will be 'point 2' as I want but it will then name point 1 as point 2 as well, so when I have added 5 points the will all read as point 5, is there a way around this at all?

Any help would be appreciated.

Writing in javascript.

```
tooltips:{ 
    callbacks: { 
        title: function (){ 
            return Name(); 
        }, label: function(tooltipItem, data){ 
                return tooltipItem.xLabel + ": " + tooltipItem.yLabel; 
        } 
    },  
} 


function Name(){
    return "Point " + i; 
}
```

Comment: How are we supposed to know what the problem is if you don't show us your code?

Comment: Updated @DibsyJr

Comment: Can you please post your html and css as well. Are you styling your chart with css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm understanding you correctly you want the `title` of a tooltip to reflect the x-axis `index` of the `data` in the chart, in which case you can do it like so:

```
tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
            title: function (tooltipItems) {
                return "Point " + (tooltipItems[0].index + 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Because one of the parameters given to `title()` in the callbacks is an array of tooltips that should be displayed, you can find out what the index is and add 1, which will reflect it's position. This way you can also scrap `Name()` and the `i` variable.

But bear in mind that this reflects position on the x-axis, meaning if you have more than one point at the same place on the x-axis then they will both have the same title.

Comment: That's the jist of it, that worked perfectly, thanks very much :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)